# jQuery clone question (cloning form input sets)

Tags: jquery

I am creating a quiz creation form that requires sections of the form to be cloned.

[see jsFiddle code example here](http://jsfiddle.net/eduQ8/19/)

My troubles come with the adding of a new set of question fields. When I click on the "ADD ANOTHER QUESTION" button, it duplicates more than one answer field (if the first answer has more than one answer field), and the cloned "ADD ANOTHER ANSWER" button does not function.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

thanks.

Comment: I don't know why you were down voted, it's a perfectly valid question, so up voted just to restore fairness :)

Comment: thanks Andrey. A down vote in less than a minute! That is a first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a couple of things:

You can create a copy of the HTML when it's empty - that way you save yourself having to clone something with values already in and needing to clear them. Just clone the empty one you already have.

You've also set the `live` on the question, but it's the 'Add an answer' button that you'd want to use live for. Live will set the handlers for anything that's added to the DOM (which you're doing). This is the reason every 'Add an answer' button except your first doesn't work.

```
var emptyQ = $("li.question").clone(),
    emptyA = $("li.answer").clone();


$("#addQuestion").live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#questioncontainer').append(emptyQ.clone());

});

$(".addAnswer").live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find(".answerContainer").append(emptyA.clone());
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/Sd9Ag/

I use `$(this).parent()` to get the question/answer container for the button that was clicked. This means the same handler works for all.

And finally - I don't know if it makes a difference, but I use `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false` on the click handlers. I don't know - I just think it's more elegant.

Answer (score 4):

You  need `.clone(true)` in order to clone its handlers as well.

And you'll probably want to do something like this for your `add another answer` handler.

```
$('.answer:last').clone().appendTo($(this).prev().find('.answerContainer')).find("input").val("");
```

Otherwise it it gets appended to all the answer containers.